# Pandas DataFrame, subset previous 3 rows to rows that meets condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subset previous 3 rows up to the row where the given condition is met. Is there a way to do it rather than get the index values and subset them step by step?

Also, I want to see the previous 3 rows to the row that meets the condition  plus 3 rows after it.

| index | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| **4** | **e** |
| 5 | f |
| 6 | g |
| 7 | h |
| 8 | i |
| 9 | j |

1. Say, row 4 meets the condition, and I want to see row 2, row 3 and row 4.
2. I want to show from row 2 to 7 subset by the row 4 that meets a condition.

Comment: "I want to subset previous 10 rows", "I want to see row 2, row 3 and row 4".  How are these sentences compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comapre value of column, shifting for [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) get starting row (here 3 previous including actual row, so subtract `1`), repeating Trues by [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html), filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last select 2 * N  rows in [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
val = 'e'
N = 3

df = df[df.col2.shift(-N + 1).eq(val).cummax()].head(N * 2)
print (df)
  col2
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
7    h
```

First solution:

```
val = 'e'
N = 3

df = df[~df.col2.shift().eq(val).cummax()].tail(N)
print (df)
  col2
2    c
3    d
4    e
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to see only row from 2 to 4 that meets the condition. Not all of the rows like you wrote above.

Comment: @DanK - It was typo.

Comment: How about pre 3 rows and pro 3 rows as well? Is there an elegant way like you gave me above?

Comment: @DanK - Can you edit question with new data and expected ouput?

Comment: ok I will do it now

Comment: I 've edited the question! thanks in advance!

Comment: @DanK - it means 2 previous, matched row and 3 next rows?

Comment: yes! :) that's exactly what I wanted to say